# Can nftables and iptables/ip6tables rules be applied at the same time? If so: what's the order of precedence?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, nftables

The question is pretty much already in the title:

**Can nftables and iptables/ip6tables rules be applied at the same time? If so: what's the order of precedence?**

The reason I ask is this: plenty of tools - especially from the realm of containerization - still rely on `iptables` and `ip6tables` to add rules and make containerized services available or unavailable to other entities on the network. So if I want to express my standard firewall rules with `nft` this has to work in parallel with `iptables`/`ip6tables`.

Or is this catered by using `iptables-legacy`/`ip6tables-legacy` with `update-alternatives` or similar? I.e. all those containerization tools continue to use what they assume is `iptables`/`ip6tables`, but in reality it's the compatibility "layer" provided by nftables?

As for the order of precedence I'd appreciate a diagram of sorts, if available to show where rules have which precedence.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is possible to use the kernel’s `iptables` and `nftables` simultaneously, but it requires some attention. The order in which the rules are applied is determined by the hook priority; legacy `iptables` default is 0, so an `nft` hook can be set to priority -1 if it should apply before `iptables`, or 1 if it should apply afterwards.

[Simultaneous NAT requires a kernel >= 4.18.](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Performing_Network_Address_Translation_(NAT)#Incompatibilities)

`iptables-nft` is designed to facilitate migration to `nft`. Installing that alongside `nft` will allow programs expecting the `iptables`/`ip6tables` interface to continue working, using `nftables` in the kernel.

This is the approach used in current containerised environments such as Kubernetes: the containers are supposed to detect which set of tables are used by the host, and use the corresponding `iptables` interface (feeding the legacy tables or `nftables`). See [Kubernetes issue #71305](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/71305) for details.

The main pain point comes from combining `iptables-nft` and `iptables-legacy`: they use the same priority, so packets go through both chains and end up nowhere.

See [When and how to use chain priorities in nftables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/419851/86440) for details of `nftables` priorities.

Comment: Thanks, this helps as it provides some context. I wasn't asking with Kubernetes in particular in mind, but the problems stands to be similar no matter the exact implementation. I just mistook the meaning of `iptables-<variant>`, thanks for clearing that up. I also just saw: `update-alternatives --display iptables` ...