# Using qemu/kvm with nftables? (without firewalld!)

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, libvirt, nftables

With libvirt/qemu/kvm you can define a bridge (or more) to be used by the guest machines. The libvirt machinery should take care of the creation of the bridge - normally called `virbr0` with `virbr0-nic` (to work around some quirks) - and will normally also take care to insert firewall rules - by way of `iptables` - to ensure connectivity (forwarding, accepting traffic between guests, sometimes denying outbound/inbound traffic on `virbr0` altogether).

Now, I am currently in the process of migrating to `nftables` and I enjoy the added flexibility and the powerful syntax which for all my use cases surpasses my past experience with `iptables`/`ip6tables` and `ipset` in tandem. Alone the fact that I can express certain rules as pertaining to the `inet` family as a whole instead of IPv4 and IPv6 individually, makes it worthwhile.

Alas, libvirt officially only supports `iptables` *or* `firewalld`.

Now my question is this: **is there a canonical way of dealing with this situation and what is it?**

Here are a few scenarios I have contemplated (all without `firewalld`):

1. use `nftables` but use the `update-alternatives` machinery to ensure libvirt will find an `iptables` (and so on) to call
2. move bridge creation away from libvirt and into `netplan`, then use other means to dynamically insert the necessary rules
3. use `nftables` but leave `iptables` active -- [from all I understand this is probably the worst idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/596497/5462), because they are bound to clash in some edge cases or in general

Answer (score 1):

My approach is below. Not sure if canonical, a pretty high bar, but seems to work well with current tools.  Fell to this approach after noticing issues getting internet access for two new Qemu/KVM Windows 10 guests on my Fedora 34 host - DHCP didn't seem to be working for the guest W10 interface and `iptables` absence was flagged in some random virtual machine manager (VMM) error message (can't remember now!).

Host:  on Fedora 34 5.13.12-200.fc34.x86_64 a) used `nftables` (already migrated) and snat for guest internet access, `firewalld` and `iptables` were already inactive b) used iproute2 to create the bridge interface with IP address at boot time

Guest: a) for both Windows 10 Qemu/KVM images specified the bridge interface, created at the host, using VMM, b) used a static IP address for the Windows 10 interface while in the guest's Windows 10 settings

Note the bridge interfaces are created at boot time. A tunnel interface is created when the Windows 10 is started and connects to the bridge.

Some pertinent host configuration snips for one bridge

1. iproute2 statements

```
/usr/sbin/ip link add name virbr1 type bridge
/usr/sbin/ip link set virbr1 up
/usr/sbin/ip address add dev virbr1 192.168.123.1/24 broadcast 192.168.123.255
```

2. nft snat

```
table nat {
      chain nat {
              type nat hook postrouting priority 100;
              policy accept;
              ip saddr 192.168.123.0/24 counter snat to *myipaddr*;
      }
}
```

The XML detail for one bridge from VMM view.

```
<interface type="bridge">
  <mac address="52:54:00:xx:xx:xx"/>
  <source bridge="virbr1"/>
  <target dev="vnet0"/>
  <model type="e1000e"/>
  <alias name="net0"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x05" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</interface>
```